# Delete words from text but only those whom contains all the different letters

Tags: c#

For example `"apple"` *should* be deleted while `"dog"` *shouldn't*.

For example: `"Dog ate my apple,so i am sad wow."`

Result would be: `"Dog ate my ,so i am sad."`

```
char[] skyrikliai = { ' ', '.', ',', '!', '?', ':', ';', '(', ')', '\t' };

 string[] parts = line.Split(skyrikliai, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
   foreach (string word in parts)
```

Comment: I am confused. You say `"apple" would not be deleted and "dog" would` yet the result does **not** contain "apple" and **does** contain dog.

Comment: You should clarify your question and also show us what you have tried

Comment: I think the question might have been better phrased "How can I remove all words from a string which contain letters repeated within that word?", but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Try  *regular expressions*, e.g  `string result = Regex.Replace(
        source,
       "[A-Za-z']+",
        match => match.Value.GroupBy(c => char.ToUpperInvariant(c)).Any(chunk => chunk.Count() > 1)
          ? ""
          : match.Value);`

Answer (score 1):

Cannot be the smartest way but works:

```
 using System.Linq;

    string line = "Dog ate my apple,so i am sad wow.";

    char[] skyrikliai = { ' ', '.', ',', '!', '?', ':', ';', '(', ')', '\t' };


    string[] parts = line.Split(skyrikliai, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    foreach (string word in parts)
    {

        char[] letters = word.ToCharArray();

        var DisintctLetters = letters.Distinct().ToArray();

        if (letters.Length != DisintctLetters.Length)

        {
            line = line.Replace(word, "");
        }

    }
   Console.WriteLine(line);
```

I assume you had a typo in your post, `Apple` should be deleted and Dog should be kept, if so:

The output will be:`Dog ate my ,so i am sad .`

Comment: foreach (string zodis in parts) {
 var pirmas = zodis.ToCharArray();
 for (int i = 0; i < zodis.Length - 1; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 1; j < zodis.Length; j++)
                    {
                        if (pirmas[i] == pirmas[j])
                        {
                            eilute.Remove(eilute.IndexOf(zodis), zodis.Length);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to remove any given word that ends with one of the named special characters.

Therefore you could use Regular Expressions: (`using System.Text.RegularExpressions;`)

```
string str = "Dog ate my apple, so I am sad wow.";
var reg = new Regex(@"\w+[.|,|!|?|:|;|(|)|\t]");
var matches = reg.Matches(str);

// access the current match with 'i' 
// keep track of how many characters were removed with 'j'
for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < matches.Count; i++)
{
    str = str.Remove(matches[i].Index - j - 1, matches[i].Length);
    j += matches[i].Length;
}
```

Output would be: `Dog ate my, so I am sad.`